# Operator that determines whether a substring belongs to a string

Tags: php, string, substring

There is a line `IRBIS MB2380 Monoblock, 23.8", Intel Celeron N3350, 4GB, 500GB, Intel HD Graphics 500, Windows 10 Home, black` or `IRU Office P2121 Monoblock, 21.5", Intel Celeron G4900, 4GB, 120GB SSD, Intel UHD Graphics 610, FreeDOS, black [1200026]`. The 4th substring between the 4th and 5th commas is selected. It is necessary to find out whether the string `SSD` belongs to the selected string (php statement), and also to determine the location of the substring `SSD` in the selected string.

Answer (score 0):

The operator you find necessary does not exist in PHP. At least I've studied the manual a couple of times and it does not list it. As I'm in no way free of error, here is the list of operators in the manual:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php

So what could be further suggestions despite the answer can only delegate any necessities back?

- Why not pick a language that suffices your operator needs? I've heard `perl` is pretty strong in string operations. Maybe it has it?
- Otherwise it perhaps suffices to write some code in PHP that does it. It wouldn't then be an operator but might do what you're looking for. But that's hard to say as you're needing an operator, and that wouldn't be it.